# Expose RestBundle JMS\Serializer не скрывает поля?

Tags: json, symfony2

User entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $balance = 0;

    /**
     * Set balance
     *
     * @param integer $balance
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setBalance($balance)
    {
        $this->balance = $balance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get balance
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBalance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Backend\UserBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Class UsersController
 * @package Backend\UserBundle\Controller
 */
class UsersController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function allUsersAction()
    {
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();

        $view = $this->view($users, 200);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function getUserAction($id)
    {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found');
        }

        $view = $this->view($user, 200);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

И при запросе на /api/v1/users/1.json он мне пишет:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "username":"admin",
   "username_canonical":"admin",
   "email":"admin",
   "email_canonical":"admin",
   "enabled":true,
   "salt":"o12yxgxp3vkk0w4sck80408w8s8o84s",
       "password":"$2y$13$o12yxgxp3vkk0w4sck804uSVjSMSB1W0qwEjunGTHomBqqoGvkW9G",
   "last_login":"2016-02-28T17:28:19+03:00",
   "locked":false,
   "expired":false,
   "roles":[  
      "ROLE_ADMIN"
   ],
   "credentials_expired":false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как так не скрывает?

У вас в выводе отстуствует поле balance, как вы и задали + ваш класс наследует от BaseUser, в котором другая "политика исключения". Скорее всего вам стоит поискать в гугле что-то вроде "JSM Serializer and parent class". И в репозитории JSM Serializer'а уже есть [issue по этому поводу](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/100)